# No TypeScript errors when accessing undefined methods of a require-d class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm starting with TypeScript on a Node.JS stack, and I've noticed that when using `require` to import classes, TypeScript doesn't have a compilation error when methods (or properties) aren't defined.

The error I'm expecting is `TS2551: Property 'undefinedMethod' does not exist on type 'typeof MyClass'. Did you mean 'definedMethod'?`, but it compiles just fine.

Then when I try and run `server.ts`, I get `TypeError: MyClass.undefinedMethod is not a function` as a regular JavaScript error.

If I use the `import {MyClass} from './MyClass';` syntax to import classes (and also change `MyClass` to `export class MyClass`), then TypeScript correctly complains that `MyClass.undefinedMethod` isn't defined.

I can't use the `import` syntax because I need to be able to include `MyClass` on both the browser client and my Node.JS server (see end for specifics).

**How can I get TypeScript to show a compile error on code that accesses an undefined method of a class?**

---

Here's the code I've tried:

`MyClass.ts` (just a basic class I want to use in both `script.ts` and `server.ts`):

```
class MyClass {

    static definedMethod () :void {
        console.log('defined');
    }

}

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = MyClass;
}
```

`server.ts`: (I only included the relevant parts about `MyClass`, there's some other stuff for `express`):

```
const MyClass = require('./MyClass');
// import MyClass = require('./MyClass'); // TS2306: File '[PATH]/source/MyClass.ts' is not a module.
// import {MyClass} from './MyClass'; // TS2306: File '[PATH]/source/MyClass.ts' is not a module.

MyClass.definedMethod();
MyClass.undefinedMethod(); // No compiliation error.
```

`script.ts`:

```
/// <reference path="../MyClass.ts" />

MyClass.definedMethod();
MyClass.undefinedMethod(); // Throws correctly TS2551: Property 'undefinedMethod' does not exist on type 'typeof MyClass'. Did you mean 'definedMethod'?
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "umd",
    "target": "es5",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "source/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I don't really know what `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` and `esModuleInterop` do, but I tried adding them to my `tsconfig.json`, and it still didn't work.

Directory structure:

- `[dist]`
- `[source]`

  - `[public]`

    - `script.ts`
  - `MyClass.ts`
  - `server.ts`
- `tsconfig.json`

---

Specifics on why I can't change `require` to `import`:

If I use the `import` and `export` syntax, my `server.ts` works, but then I can't use `/// <reference path=` on my `script.ts` because error `TS2304: Cannot find name 'MyClass'.`

If I just change to use `import` in `server.ts`, I get `TS2306: File '[PATH]/source/MyClass.ts' is not a module.`

Comment: Did you try exporting from `MyClass.ts` instead of using `module.exports`? The reason the error says it's not a module is because it doesn't export anything (at least in the code you've shared).

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, I tried that, but it means I can't load the compiled `MyClass.js` in the browser. Using the `module.exports` means I can load it in both the browser and the server (at least afaik, there's probably a better way to do it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> when using require to import classes, TypeScript doesn't have a compilation error when methods (or properties) aren't defined.

With `const MyClass = require('./MyClass');`, `MyClass` gets an `any` type. `any`opts out of type checking, so you literally can invoke anything on it. That is, because the type signature of `require` looks like [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f4e58f2e65ccf8552f6372acff796398009a36d3/types/node/globals.d.ts#L191):

```
interface NodeRequireFunction {
    (id: string): any;
}
```

> How can I get TypeScript to show a compile error on code that accesses an undefined method of a class?

First, change to ES import-syntax again to enable type checking in `server.ts`:

```
// MyClass.ts
export class MyClass { ... }

// server.ts
import { MyClass } from './MyClass'
```

Create a module `global.ts` (you could also drop it in `MyClass.ts`), assign `MyClass` class to a property in the browser `Window` global scope:

```
import { MyClass } from "./MyClass";

// augment global type declarations inside a module with "declare global"
declare global {
  // browser window interface
  interface Window {
    // we want the class constructor (not instance) type, hence typeof MyClass
    MyClass: typeof MyClass; 
  }
}

// this is the actual run-time assignment
window.MyClass = MyClass;
```

Import this file at the top of your module root as a side effect:

```
// root.ts
import "./global"
```

In `script.ts`, drop the Triple-Slash Directive `/// <reference path="../MyClass.ts" />` (we don't need that type anymore). E.g. after having bundled all modules with Webpack & Co. and using  the bundle and `script.ts` scripts, you now should be able to write:

```
window.MyClass.definedMethod()
```

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Your explanation of the `any` type from `require` was really helpful. Do you think it'd be possible to just type-hint the `const MyClass`? I tried that, but it also didn't work. I'll check out your solution tonight when I get off work and let you know if it works or not.

Comment: hmm possible - yes. Would I do it? No . In principle, you can cast `any` like you want like `const MyClass_ = require('./MyClass') as typeof MyClass` but it really seems to be a bit fishy.

Comment: Yeah, so I've just tried using Webpack again, I think what I got wrong last time was pointing Webpack to my `server.ts` instead of my `script.ts`. I'm just porting over my actual codebase to use imports now, but my test repo works fine now, thanks :)